# How can I use Docker Hub for .Net Core projects despite a US-sanctions block?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, docker, .net-core

I am from Iran. Because of sanctions from US it is very hard to use Docker in my server. But we really need to use micro-service, as times goes on our project is getting bigger and bigger and we need to think of some thing to manage the complexity.

I can't connect to Docker Hub from my server in Iran, so I need to set up proxy every time I want to pull project from Docker Hub. That period my server will not respond to users. It is funny that one of reasons I want to promote the system (by .net core and microservice and Docker and ...) is to avoid issues on server like being down or inactive.

Could I solve this by looking at alternatives to Docker in .net core ?

Comment: You can use kubernetes instead

Comment: @DevVis ,as I know docker and kubernetes are working together, cant separate them

Comment: You don’t keep docker, kubernetes or any other magic buzzword.  Just deploy your dot net core app to IIS or self-hosted.

Comment: Docker is open source, so you should be able to use it despite the sanctions. If you believe you cannot, please edit your question to explain why.

Comment: Docker is open source But what about Docker hub? Is it open source too? this is the problem 

I am searching about it

Comment: Would you be more specific about your actual problem? For example, can you not connect to Docker Hub from Iran? It is possible that they are legally obligated to stop you connecting, and they may disagree with this legal imposition. However, they are a US corporation, and have to obey the law.

Comment: That is correct I cant connect to docker hub from my server which is in Iran,so I need to set up proxy every time I want to pull project from docker hub. that period my server will not respond to users. it is funny that one of reasons I want to promote the system (by .net core and microservice and docker and  ...) is to avoid issues on server like being done or inactive.

I guess registry docker which is open source solves my problem.

Comment: Setting up a dedicated proxy server or VPN should give you access to public Docker Hub. If your server won't respond when it is pulling images, then perhaps you have to look at what CPU load it is under - you may need a more capable server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for my problem is to use docker along with registry docker (docker-hub) which both are open-source. This solves my sanctions limitation problem.

Answer (score 2):

**docker != microservice**.

Docker helps you deploying multiple services on an orchestrator (e. g. Kubernetes) but you can also deploy your monolith in a single docker container....

Depending on **where** you want to deploy your application, you can use a Framework / Programming Model like Azure ServiceFabric or you just create multiple ASP.NET Core Web Apps that represents your microservices and deploy them to an IIS. In case of the later, you probably want some kind of API Gateway in place so the client (your MVC application) doesn't need to know each endpoint URL.

Comment: thx @Martin

I know docker != microservice but every tutorial I searched was about using microservices along with docker .

every micro service uses a container and docker manages the containers 
am I right ?
I want to use a software which does same job as docker but not docker
is it possible?

Comment: The main benefit of docker is that it allows you to package a service with all its *dependencies* to a container and be able to deploy / run it anywhere. It doesn't "manage" your container. Its the orchestrator that ensures a container gets restartet if its crashed or that a certain number of instances are up.

Comment: Is there any alternative for docker?
 OR
Should I use docker any way ? How hard that would be if I dont use docker?

Comment: It depends. It might be a lot easier for you to not use docker and just deploy your services to a web server. It really depends on your requirements / hosting target...

Comment: "Service-oriented architecture" was a really trendy buzzword during the XML era 20 years ago, well before Linux containers existed.  There's nothing in the pattern that requires Docker, it's just a deployment convenience.

Comment: @DavidMaze 100% agree